# Recording Data change every 30s but in the top row which starts from Row33

Tags: excel, vba

[DataRecordSnapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KReK9.png)Im trying to record data change every 30 secs, its recording the data fine however I want the most recent record on top of the row while shifting the previous record below with time stamp in columnA[DataRecordingImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQhNX.png), data recording row starts from Column A Row 33, can someone help me in acheiving that.

here is the VBA code.

```
Sub LogValuesEvery30Seconds()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim lastRowBToH As Long
    Dim column As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FYRNIFTY")

    lastRowBToH = 32 ' Initialize with row 32 to start from row 33
    For Each column In Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
        lastRowBToH = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(lastRowBToH, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row)
    Next column
    
    newRow = lastRowBToH + 1
    
    ws.Cells(newRow, "A").Value = Now()
    
    ws.Cells(newRow, "B").Value = ws.Range("K13").Value - ws.Range("C13").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "C").Value = ws.Range("K14").Value - ws.Range("C14").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "D").Value = ws.Range("K15").Value - ws.Range("C15").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "E").Value = ws.Range("K16").Value - ws.Range("C16").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = ws.Range("K17").Value - ws.Range("C17").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "G").Value = ws.Range("K18").Value - ws.Range("C18").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "H").Value = ws.Range("K19").Value - ws.Range("C19").Value
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"),
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly ... I've commented the changed/additional lines in the below code so you can see what they are doing. Note that `lastRowBToH` and `column` are both unused in this code but I have left them in here in case you use them outside of this snippet. Your `Application.OnTime` line was also missing the Sub name which I guess is just a typo ... I've replaced it in this code, but please check it is what you initially were using.

```
Sub LogValuesEvery30Seconds()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim lastRowBToH As Long
    Dim column As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FYRNIFTY")
    
    ' row number to insert at
    newRow = 33
    ' insert the new row
    ws.Rows(newRow).Insert
    ' format it the same as the row below (otherwise will take on the formatting of the row above)
    ws.Rows(newRow + 1).Copy ws.Rows(newRow)
    ws.Rows(newRow).ClearContents
            
    ws.Cells(newRow, "A").Value = Now()
    
    ws.Cells(newRow, "B").Value = ws.Range("K13").Value - ws.Range("C13").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "C").Value = ws.Range("K14").Value - ws.Range("C14").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "D").Value = ws.Range("K15").Value - ws.Range("C15").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "E").Value = ws.Range("K16").Value - ws.Range("C16").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = ws.Range("K17").Value - ws.Range("C17").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "G").Value = ws.Range("K18").Value - ws.Range("C18").Value
    ws.Cells(newRow, "H").Value = ws.Range("K19").Value - ws.Range("C19").Value
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "LogValuesEvery30Seconds"
End Sub
```